# How to check if field is required in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I wanna create and save an Entity from data passed through HTTP POST way.

How can I enlist all the fields from an Entity that are required, so that my REST API method could check whether all required data have been passed through HTTP POST (to fulfill new created Entity), and send a response with an error if there are missing any (e.g. "There are missing fields which are required: "title", "message"...)?

Comment: Read the validation chapter of the symfony book

Comment: Ok then. I tried to read Doctrine's annotations, but you might be right about leveraging the validator service. Thx for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it are the validations of Symfony 2, like Carlos Granados mentioned in the comments. Probably the cleaner solution.

Anyhow, to answer the question: You can use Doctrines `ClassMetadata` to check if a field is nullable:

```
$metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('My\Entity\Class');
$isRequired = !$metadata->isNullable("myField");
```

And put this in a loop to get all required fields:

```
$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('Application\Entity\Task');
$fieldNames = $metadata->getFieldNames();
$required = array();
foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
    if(!$metadata->isNullable($fieldName)) {
        $required[] = $fieldName;
    }
}
```